# concatenating two object keys in JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
console.log(a) ; // console window result= 1
console.log(b);// console window result= 2

var c = {a : b};// any recommendations here?
var d = JSON.stringify(c);
d = encodeURIComponent(d);
```

I need final result of d = {1:2};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use computed property

```
var c = {[a] : b};
```